# Horizontal box plot with multiple boxes in one row with plotly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, plotly-dash

I am new to plotly and this is one of my first attempt to visualise data in an interactive way. And now I have run into a conceptual problem.
I want to plot horizontal boxes plot with plotly and I am following [this tutorial on horizontal box graphs in plotly](https://plot.ly/python/box-plots/) however having the data in the structure like this:

```
data = [
    {
        'x': [0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3],
        'y': ['day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2'],
        'name':'kale',
        'marker': {
            'color': '#3D9970'
        },
        'boxmean': False,
        'orientation': 'h',
        "type": "box",
    }]
```

You can only plot one continuous box in a row.
What I want to achieve is something like:
 [image: desired plot]
I have a list of actions and I want to plot them to show which actions are performed at what time in a day and how long they last. Some of the actions are performed multiple times in one day, and hence I need a way to visualise it.
Do you know if this is even possible with plotly?

If you want to down vote my question, please provide a constructive critique on why you are doing so.

Comment: How are the spaces determined? `NaN` values?

Comment: It depends on how can it be plotted. For now I only have start time and end time, as a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to this problem would be to use shapes instead of bars. Documentation can be found [here](https://plot.ly/python/shapes/)